# Flot: time-tick at 0:00

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have chart showing data, with X-axis showing time. I would like to have ticks in the X axis being placed on 0:00 time each day. I had that working before I've updated to newest Flot.

```
...
xaxis:
  {
    ticks: 6,
    mode:"time",
    timezone:<cfoutput>"#varDEVICETZ#"</cfoutput>,
    timeformat: "<center>%Y-%m-%d<br>%H:%M</center>"
},
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Which version were you using previously, and which are you using now?  I ask because Flot didn't support timezones in 0.7; that was added in 0.8.  So is that timezone option something you added after upgrading?

Comment: @DNS before 0.6, now the latest one (0.8). We've used to have min:0, max:1, but it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in 0.8; we've fixed it in master, and it will be released as part of 0.8.1 in a few days.